# Auto Pop textarea once page is load

Tags: java, php, javascript, html

The Attached pick is my current working User Interface.  It contains the description my my question regarding Auto pop text area field.

[image: ScreenShot]

I have a text field which auto generates a link once the page is loaded.  Now I want to duplicate that same link and make it appear in a text area.

I have been trying to sort this out but its not working for text area, I can get it to work if the field is a text field but just calling it this way:

```
Value="the id of the textarea that generate the link"
```

How do I get this to work for a text area?

Comment: *"The Attached pick is my current working User Interface"*  Huh?  SO has no 'attachment facility', an image can be linked to at an image sharing site if you do not have the reputation to embed images, if you mean 'picture' then it is either 'picture' or 'pic' (no K).

Comment: You're question is very confusing.  e.g. *"Auto pop text area field"* ?!?

Comment: @Apulo: You can post a link to the picture, and one of us can edit your post and attach it for you :)

Comment: http://s1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/?action=view&current=pop.png

Comment: http://s1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/?action=view&current=pop.png

Hi guys sorry for the late reply, the link above is the picture i have in my photobucket  account, my user name is Apulo_Cosmas, feel free to get to it, i will appricate it if someone can help me attache it on stackoverflow. thanks guys waiting for your help

Answer (score 0):

After logged in for the first time, the input box which shows the unique link has `returningcode` in the id attribute and after refreshing the page, it changes to `successcode`. In addition to it, I found that the 2 HTML elements having the same id so we can not go with #selector.

This should work:

```
$(window).load({
    var unique_url = $('div#monetize-form > ul > li:eq(19) > input[type="text"]').val();
    $('div#monetize-form > ul > li:eq(13) > textarea').val(unique_url);
    $('div#monetize-form > ul > li:eq(14) > textarea').val(unique_url);
});
```

Comment: Hi Codeformer, correct me if am wrong. i set the script like this on my page head section. <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  
 $('input').val('successcode');
 $('textarea').html('successcode');
 
}
})
</script> and in my html (textarea) i called id="sucesscode" but its not working. the sucesscode is the ID of the textfeild that generates the link. <textarea class="field6" id="successcode"></textarea> waiting for your reply.

Comment: I'm pretty much unclear about what you've done and are trying to do. Would like to see your code? Put it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Am sure am doing the wrong thing here, can you help me correct this:  http://jsfiddle.net/kbAwt/

Comment: Both input and textarea have the similar id - not a good idea. Explain now what should happen when the page loads up in jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Codeformer, i have a textfeild which auto generates a link once the page is loaded (refer to the picture above). my problem is i want the same link generated in the textfeild to auto populate in the textarea once the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks Codeformer, its about 90% to what i want, but instead of having this link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962473/auto-pop-textarea-once-page-is-load/9962913) static in the code, i want to have an ID called (successcode), this is because the link generated are random links at Unique. so i need to Use an ID from the textfield pointing it to the textarea so that once the textfield generates any random link, the same link will be auto poped in textarea feild .

Comment: Let me get it straight: Once the page is loaded the link is generated into a textbox (which has a copy button next to it as per the image attached) and then immediately you want to copy the same url into your textarea dynamically using JS. Is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Exactly, but i don't have to click the copy button to copy the link, i want the link to be inserted automatically once the page is loaded. with out clicking any button to trigger it. thanks.

Comment: Thats very simple but make sure the link has to be generated before the page is loaded completely. And then this code will run: 
`$(window).load({
    $('input').val($('#your-input-which-has-a-link').val());    
    $('textarea').html($('#your-input-which-has-a-link').val());
});`.

Comment: Hello Codeformer, its works fine but i want it to be returning what ever that is stored in the unique id field. meaning that i don't have a particular static link in the unique link field. so i suggest to have an ID to call the unique feild each time the page is reloaded the unique like will be returned.

Comment: What do you mean by "so i suggest to have an ID to call the unique feild each time the page is reloaded the unique link will be returned."?

Comment: what am trying to say is that, if you notice, the link is static in the code: (function autoGenerateLink() {
   // your tricky code goes here to generate the unique url 
   return 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962473/auto-pop-textarea-once-page-is-load/9962913';  
}) the textfield i have generates a particular code each time the page loads, having an Id="" in the area you called the returning fucntion is better so that when the page reloads, it will send the currently generated links to the textarea

Comment: Of course I've put the static link for the demo purpose but you need to add your code which generates the link for you.

Comment: Were there is no particular code in the page that generates the link, Am using Launcheffectapp to generate the link and thats what performs the maggic

Comment: what to do with that link? I'm still confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: visit http://prelaunch.adgoggle.com at the homepage, register with testtest007@yahoo.com, and take note of the link there, press F5 to refresh, it will take you back to the mail page, use this email address again testest008@yahoo.com, you will notice the 2links are not the same, so i want the links that appear on that form to appear in the the text area at the same time it appear in the test feild